# ASP .NET Core 2.0 Deployment (code not executing)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-2.0

I am very new to deploying applications to AWS, specifically Elastic Beanstalk through the "publish to AWS" feature built into visual studio 2017 after downloading the AWS toolkit.

My problem is that when I deploy my application which is a .NET core 2.0 empty application, it seems to deploy correctly (green health and no errors) and the "hello world" page is working when I navigate to the URL, but none of the functionality of the application is working.

I have a theory but I am not sure how to fix it.

When I run the code locally on visual studio 2017 everything works perfectly. When I deploy, I get no errors but code is not executed.

The application I made makes use of a main method which cascades all the other methods of the project, so I am assuming that my project is successfully deployed, but I don't have any commands, scripts or json files that states to start the main method.

How would you do that from visual studio/elastic beanstalk console?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: @abydal I don't think that the code is that useful to examine. When starting up the application a program.cs (contains main) and startup.cs file that is used for start up. My main calls an instance of a db class I made to make a new table in Microsoft Sql Server and thats it. When I hit the green arrow in visual studio it works. When I use deployment AWS wizard and place code on their server It doesnt work. I dont know if I have to do something after deploying it from visual studio to elastic beanstalk like sometype of "run" button.

Comment: @abydal I did get a message in visual studio saying in main failed to retrieve EC2 credentials but it does not affect my instance health so don't think that is the problem. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ok, Sounds like your code is correct, but you mention a db class. Do you have a database to connect to when you deploy to amazon? In VS you usually use a local db, but that won't work when your code runs on AWS servers.

Comment: @abydal Maybe the communication between EC2 and elastic beanstalk is failing because of IAM user group settings? I have no idea though.

Comment: You need to provide more info on `the "hello world" page is working when I navigate to the URL, but none of the functionality of the application is working` part. Screen shot?

Comment: @abydal I have a microsoft Sql Server database. I know that is not the problem though because like I said when I run locally the creating of tables work. Maybe its because I have permissions to use AWS locally but the server does not? That seems unlikely though.

Comment: @LexLi It is just the default functionality when you create an ASP .NET core 2.0 empty project in visual studio. When you run the application in VS a browser opens displaying hello world. After deploying it gives me a url ending in .elasticbeanstalk.com and I see hello world. So I was just saying that I know the server is not crashing.

Comment: @Lexli As to the functionality not working, when I run project in VS I call DB instance that creates new table in my Microsoft Sql server db, but when I deploy to server literally nothing happens. (i.e. my main is not being executed)

Comment: Edit the question please. Words in comments are hard to read.

Comment: @LexLi Sorry I did not mean to make it difficult to read. I will try to edit. What do you mean "words in comments"? Is it the words in parenthesis?